# How to initialize variables in chefspec which is needed to be used in recipe

Tags: ruby, rspec, chef-infra

I have the recipe template resource block below:

```
 os_ver = node['platform_version'].to_f
 REPO_TEMPLATE = ''
 if (os_ver >= 6) && (os_ver < 7)
   REPO_TEMPLATE = 'epel.repo.rhel6.erb'
 elsif (os_ver >= 7) && (os_ver < 8)
   REPO_TEMPLATE = 'epel.repo.rhel7.erb'
 end

 template EPEL_REPO_FILE do
   source REPO_TEMPLATE
   owner 'root'
   group 'root'
   mode '0644'
   action :create
 end
```

And I made the unit test chefspec like this:

```
describe 'cos::upgrade_rpms' do
  let(:chef_run) do
    ChefSpec::SoloRunner.new do |node|
      node.set['platform_version'] = '7.0'
      REPO_TEMPLATE = 'epel.repo.rhel7.erb'
    end.converge(described_recipe)
  end
  it 'creates a epel repo' do
    expect(chef_run).to create_template('/etc/yum.repos.d/epel.repo').with(
      source: 'epel.repo.rhel7.erb'
      owner: 'root',
      group: 'root',
      mode: '0644'
    )
end
```

The unit test will fail which says: source is **''** not source: **'epel.repo.rhel7.erb'**.
It seems that REPO_TEMPLATE set up in test make no effect. Can some tell how to mock the value in unit tests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`platform_version` is an automatic attribute, they're filled in by fauxhai usually with the os and version you give in your runner or in the global Rspec configuration like this (quoted from Readme of ChefSpec and adapted to your use case):

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  # Specify the operating platform to mock Ohai data from (default: nil)
  config.platform = 'redhat'

  # Specify the operating version to mock Ohai data from (default: nil)
  config.version = '7.0'
end
```

Quote from [ChefSpec Documentation](https://github.com/sethvargo/chefspec#automatic-attributes) for modifying an automatic attribute at runner time:

```
describe 'example::default' do
  let(:chef_run) do
    ChefSpec::SoloRunner.new do |node|
      node.automatic['memory']['total'] = '512kB'
    end.converge(described_recipe)
  end
end
```